# trigger after update lookup field not updated?

Tags: trigger

```
 trigger countingof on lead (after insert,after update,after delete){
   set<id>  conId = new set<id>();
   map<id,list<lead>> countle= new map<id,list<lead>>();
   if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert || trigger.isUpdate ){
    for(lead c: trigger.new){
      if(c.owner_type__c!=null){
           conId.add(c.owner_type__c);
       }
     }
   }
  if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isDelete){
    for(lead c:trigger.old){
       if(c.owner_type__c!=null){
          conId.add(c.owner_type__c);
        }
     }
  }
 list<lead> leadlist= [select id ,owner_type__c  , no_of_lead__c  from lead where owner_type__c In :conId];
  for(lead a :leadlist){
      countle.put(a.owner_type__c, leadlist);
  }
 list<lead> lst=new list<lead>();
 list<lead> countlist = [select id, no_of_lead__c,owner_type__c  from lead where owner_type__c in :conId];
    for(lead a : countlist){ 
       list<lead> lstt=countle.get(a.owner_type__c);
       a.no_of_lead__c= lstt.size();
       system.debug('@@@a' +a);  
       if(a.owner_type__c!=null){   
          lst.add(a);
       }
       update lst;
    }
}
```

> Error:Apex trigger countingof caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: countingof: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your trigger

1. I see that the way you form the "countle" map is not correct .
2. I see update statement inside FOR loop
3. Very important ,you are facing recursion .

You are trying to update leads which in turn again will call your trigger and this will lead to recursion and salesforce reports as unexpected error .

There is a free tutorial on [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/apex_triggers) that will guide you how to write effective triggers .

If you are trying to update leads in same context ,you can stop recursion via static boolean .

Look at the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000133752&language=en_US) article to understand what is recursion and how you can prevent it

Comment: if i remove after update and isupdate so its work properlly.  i understood and fix for loop which is running in updatelist.